# insert DIV text in angular

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I have a list of products, added to the HTML dynamically. When a user clicks a product, it  must be added to the cart (think, [jQueryUI shopping cart example](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart)).

**HTML**:
From this dynamic list, how do I retrieve the clicked Product and insert it to the JSON object?

```
<li ng-model="selectProduct" ng-click="addProduct()" ng-repeat="product in Products">
  {{product}}
</li>
```

**Script**

```
$scope.addProduct = function () {
    $scope.myProducts.push($scope.selectProduct); // add text of the selected product
};

$scope.myObject = {
   myProducts: []
};
```

In jQuery it would be something like

```
$("p").click(functions (){
  var aa = $(this).text()
  myObject = {
    'selectProduct': aa
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it as a parameter, so it would work something like this

HTML:

```
<li ng-click="addProduct(product)" ng-repeat="product in Products">
  {{product}}
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.Products = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
$scope.myObject = {
   myProducts: []
};

$scope.addProduct = function (thisProduct) {
    $scope.myObject.myProducts.push(thisProduct);
};
```

A working example is at http://jsfiddle.net/trMKQ/ (click on the product names to see).

Comment: In angular you can actually just use the code `this.product` when using a click even within a ngRepeat directive.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Personally I think passing the parameter makes it a bit clearer what's happening though.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @mikel 's answer, you can actually just access the model directly.

So your html code would be;

```
<li ng-click="addProduct()" ng-repeat="product in Products">
  {{product}}
</li>
```

And your angular click method would be;

```
$scope.addProduct = function(){
    var selectedProduct = this.product; // where product = product in Products.
};
```

If you changed the repeat directive to `item in Products` then the matching js would be `this.item;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'data' property to indicate clicked product:

```
$('.product').click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', '1');
});
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question